# How to combine 2 arrays based on condition in mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have an orders collection in which there is items field which is `[ { itemId: ObjectId, quantity: number } ]`

I want to populate itemId with the respective document using aggregation but lookup stage makes a separate array

Desired result: `[ { itemId: {} , quantity: number } ]`

Tried: 
[Aggregation pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qleWb.png)

Is there a way to combine these array as such i get the desired result or is there any other way?

Comment: post please sample data and desired result. Your example is wrong json and not clear what are you trying to do

Comment: Post also sample data where we need to use `$lookup`

Comment: Added pipeline picture in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just use a $unwind and $project operations to overwrite the itemId field once you have done the $lookup?

Like this:

```
db.orders.aggregate([{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "items",
        "localField": "itemId",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "item"
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$item"
}, {
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "itemId": "$item",
        "quantity": 1
    }
}]);
```

**UPDATE**

Having seen what the data looks like you could try doing something like this:

```
db.orders.aggregate([{
    "$unwind": "$items"
}, {
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "items",
        "localField": "items.itemId",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "item"
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$item"
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "items": {
            "$push": {
                "itemId": "$item",
                "quantity": "$items.quantity"
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

The first $unwind turns the array of items into individual objects that then can be used in the $lookup to get their record from the item collection. Second $unwind does the same thing for the new item field. And the final $group pulls every back together based on the original _id from orders and the $push reformats the items field into what you want.

Comment: Both are arrays so doing this overrides the whole array